# Manually invite a Bot to a Microsoft Teams call

Tags: c#, botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm trying to build a bot that could join a Teams call, and then record its content.
The problem i'm having is that i yet have not come to any solution to be able to add the bot to the call via the Teams UI.

Is there a way to do this? Its mentioned on Microsoft's documentation but there's nothing else about it.
There's also an open Issue on [Github](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/issues/57) but there hasn't been any updates in the past year.

Thanks

Comment: Please take a look at [calling and meeting bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/calls-and-meetings/registering-calling-bot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding adding the bot to the meeting:

There's some sample code here. https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/blob/master/Samples/V1.0Samples/LocalMediaSamples/AudioVideoPlaybackBot/FrontEnd/Bot/Bot.cs

Specifically look at JoinCallAsync(), which will enable the bot to join the meeting, taking the input as meeting link.

I'm not sure if there is a way to invite a bot to the call, but the bot could defenitely join the meeting , given the teams meeting link.

(Of course, this would be under the assumption that the bot has sufficient graph permissions as listed here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/calls-and-meetings/registering-calling-bot)

Comment: From Review: Hi, while links are a great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)